# MUI DataGrid display Airtable data

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, airtable

I am using Airtable as a temporary database for basic data, and using Material-UI DataGrid to display it. I am able to retrieve the data from Airtable and have it show in console.log, but cannot send it to the DataGrid to display.

This is the MUI DataGrid - https://mui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version 
This is the Airtable npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/airtable

[This is the console.log displaying the data retrieved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHLL.png)

[This is where the error is on the site, it only displays the column header, not the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL4r9.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Airtable from "airtable";
const base = new Airtable({ apiKey: "*****" }).base(
  "*****"
);

const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme) => ({
    container: {
      marginTop: "10vh",
    },
  }),
  {}
);
const col = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  { field: "name", headerName: "Institution Name", width: 150 },
  { field: "town", headerName: "Location Town", width: 150 },
  { field: "state", headerName: "State", width: 150 },
];
export default function CE3() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    base("Table 1")
      .select({
        maxRecords: 3,
        view: "Grid view",
      })
      .eachPage((records, fetchNextPage) => {
        setRows(records);
        console.log(records);
        fetchNextPage();
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container fixed={true} className={classes.container}>
        Select at least <strong>1</strong> college
        <br></br>
        {rows && (
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={col}
            pageSize={5}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
            checkboxSelection
            disableSelectionOnClick
          />
        )}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set a height to the parent of the DataGrid so that the DataGrid can match this height (see https://mui.com/components/data-grid/layout/#predefined-dimensions)

Or set the `autoHeight` prop to true (see https://mui.com/components/data-grid/layout/#auto-height)