# I dont know why my DataGrid MUI component is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Im trying to use MUI (MaterialUI's React Component library) for the first time. I followed the [installation process shown in documentation](https://mui.com/pt/getting-started/installation/) and im trying to use the [DataGrid component](https://mui.com/pt/components/data-grid/) in my React project.

Im trying to use the first example shown in the documentation page as a template.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) => `${params.row.firstName || ""} ${params.row.lastName || ""}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
];

const Paciente = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paciente;
```

Its the exactly same code at the documentation. Now, what is happening:

[image]

Can someone help me with that?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "junta-dashboard-2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@trendyol-js/react-carousel": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.3.2",
    "react-markdownit": "^2.5.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the parent element does not have height. Then, the grid does not know how much space is available.

The two solutions are:

- set parent element `height`
- use prop `autoHeight`

More details on the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707313/17578611